# Komodo Edit and Notepad++ ::: Pros & Cons ::: Python dev

Tags: python, editor, notepad++, komodo, komodoedit

I'm using Notepad++ for python development, and few days ago I found out about free Komodo Edit.

I need Pros and Cons for Python development between this two editors...

Comment: They're both free, so why not try them both and see which you prefer?

Comment: One thing to consider, notepad++ is very, very, lightweight and fast on your system (i am using a fast i7 with 64gbram + ssd, and it is still very noticeable) - Komodo is just sluggish, heavy and slow...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have worked a bit with Python programming for Google App Engine, which I started out in Notepad++ and then recently shifted over to Komodo using two excellent startup tutorials - both of which are conveniently linked from [this blog post](http://blogs.activestate.com/2008/04/komodo-does-it) (direct: [here](http://abaditya.com/2008/04/19/a-pseudo-ide-for-google-app-engine-komodo-edit/) and [here](http://www.toddnemet.com/using-komodo-edit-as-an-ide-for-google-app-engine/)).

- Komodo supports the basic
  organization of your work into
  Projects, which Notepad++ does not
  (apart from physical folder
  organization).
- The custom commands
  toolbar is useful to keep track of
  numerous frequently-used commands
  and even link to URLs (like online
  documentation and the like).
- It has a working (if sometimes clunky)
  code-completion mechanism.

In short, it's an IDE which provides all the benefits thereof.

Notepad++ is simpler, much MUCH faster to load, and does support some basic configurable run commands; it's a fine choice if you like doing all your execution and debugging right in the commandline or Python shell.  My advice is to try both!

Comment: thanks, fixed dead URL and added direct links!

Answer (score 9):

I just downloaded and started using Komodo Edit. I've been using Notepad++ for awhile. Here is what I think about some of the features:

Komodo Edit Pros:

- You can jump to a function definition, even if it's in another file (I love this)
- There is a plugin that displays the list of classes, functions and such for the current file on the side. Notepad++ used to have a plugin like this, but it no longer works with the current version and hasn't been updated in a while.

Notepad++ Pros:

- If you select a word, it will highlight all of those words in the current document (makes it easier to find misspellings), without having to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.
- When working with HTML, when the cursor is on/in a tag, the starting and ending tags are both highlighted

Anyone know if either of those last 2 things is possible in Komodo Edit?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first point.  In Komodo, hit Ctrl+F on the current word to search for it.  That process will hightlight all matches in the file.  Hit Esc to undo the highlighting.

Comment: selecting a word is more handy then ctrl + F and type the word, right?

Comment: Np++ has that two Komodo pros:
[TagsJump](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tagsjump/) plugin allows to jump to a definition even it is in another file.
[Function list](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/) can list definitions in the current file for many programing languages.

Answer (score 8):

I use Komodo edit.  The main reasons are:  Intellisense (not as good as VisualStudio, but Python's a hard language to do intellisense for) and cross-platform compatibility.  It's nice being able to use the same editor on my Windows machine, my linux machine, and my macbook with little to no change in feel.

Comment: Komodo is truly cross-platform. Keeping the same look and feel no matter where you are. I love that.

Answer (score 7):

I use both Komodo Edit and Notepad++.

Notepad++ is a lot quicker to launch and it's more lightweight, so I often use it for quick one-off editing.

I use Komodo Edit for major projects, like my django and wxPython applications. KE is a full-featured IDE, so it has a lot more features.

Main advantages of Komodo Edit for programming Python:

- Manage groups of files as projects
- Use custom commands to run files, run nosetests/pylint, etc.
- Auto complete & syntax checking
- Mozilla extension system, with several useful extensions available
- Write macros in JavaScript or Python
- Spell checking

Some of the little things that Notepad++ is missing for Python development:

- Doesn't auto-indent after a colon
- <s>You can't set tabs/spaces on a file-type basis (I like to use tabs for HTML)</s>
- <s>No code completion or tooltips</s>
- No on-the-fly syntax checking

Comment: Notepad++ has a plugin menu from which you can add a spell checker and other tools. I use the [NppExec plugin](https://gist.github.com/CTimmerman/3fc259d7867c38f6919e) with scripts to process and run my Python files, whose output is highlighted and linked in Notepad++..

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know , Notepad++ doesn't show you the docstring each method has .

Comment: Function parameter hints do, but not all functions are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\APIs\python.xml`

Answer (score 4):

A downside I found of Notepad++ for Python is that it tends (for me) to silently mix tabs and spaces. I know this is configurable, but it caught me out, especially when trying to work with other people using different editors / IDE's, so take care.

Comment: Ctrl+H, find `____` replace `\t`, find `__` replace `\t`, works for me, except when somebody used 3-space indents. (replace _ with a space)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Komodo yet (the download never quite finished on the slow connection I was on at the time), but I use Eclipse with PyDev regularly and enjoy the "IDE" features described by the other respondents. However, I'm also regularly frustrated by how much of a resource hog it is.

I downloaded Notepad++ recently (much smaller download size ;-) ) and have been enjoying it quite a bit. The editor itself is nice and fast and it looks to be extensible. I'm hoping to copy some of my favorite features from IDE into Notepad++ and migrate, at some distant point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to choose between Notepad++ and Komodo i would choose PyScripter ;.)
Seriously I consider PyScripter as a great alternative...

Answer (score -4):

Downloaded both myself.  Like Komodo better.

Komodo Pros:  Like it better.  Does more.  Looks like an IDE.  Edits Django templates

Notepad++ Cons: Don't like it as much.  Does less.  Looks less like and IDE.

Comment: +1 I laughed for a while

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this correctly...if something isn't as good as something else, then the *other thing* is better. Mind. Blown. +1 `:D`

Comment: @Droogans: Nope.  Not understanding it correctly.  If something isn't as good as something else, it simply isn't as good.  Don't read things into the answer that aren't there.  The question was vague; the answer is precisely as vague as the question.